# Select a drop down menu Applescript

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, applescript

Apologies in advance, I am very new to scripting.

I am trying to automating using applescript, the fill of a dropdown that contains:

```html
<select id="theId" class="form-control" data-reactid="..." title="..."
<option value="theValue" class data-reactid="..."></option>
```

I used this script:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
activate
tell active tab of front window
    execute javascript "document.getElementById('theId').value='theValue';"
        
end tell``end tell
```

The form is filling with the correct value.

The problem is, when doing manually (clicking), the value clicked in the dropdown changes the status of the page but when automating that doesn't work. Also, when I type in a text area, for example, the value of the drop drown resets to it's default value.

How can I "submit" the dropdown to be active?

I tried this also but doesn't work either:

```
execute javascript "document.getElementById('').submit();"
```

If anyone has a clue,
Thanks for your help!

Comment: My guess is that the dropdown has an event handler that is not being triggered when you programmatically update the selected value.

Comment: Thanks @user3579815, I see in the related js script, a onClickCallBack next to theId, that would be it? How can I trigger it?